# children last and focus

Tags: jquery

```
addNewRow()
alert("ok");
var tr = $("#invoice_item").children("tr:last")
var col = row.find(".qty").select();
```

The above code for append new row to tbody by function `"addNewRow()"` after that I need to move the cursor to a new row

My code is working but if the removed alert("ok"); the cursor will be in an old row not on a new row.

Please help

Comment: include html code also with post

Comment: I think you have a mistake in the last line, can it be `var col = tr.find(".qty").select();` ?

Comment: sorry  , var tr = row.find(".qty").select();    the cursor will be in an old row not on a new row.

Comment: how can i upload the PHP & JS files to check the code